# pointer-events: none is not working

Tags: html, css

I am creating a web application where I made a clickable card. I want to disable the click event on anchor tag for zero Opportunities.

But `pointer-events: none;` is not working.

I have setup a snippet  here for better understanding.

```css
.fc-card-header {
    background: #1976d2;
    padding: 24px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
}
.svg-icon svg {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
}
```

```html
<a href="cmOpportunitySummary" class="white" style="text-decoration:none;pointer-events: none; cursor: default;;">
<div class="fc-card-header">
    <div class="grid-row">
        <div class="grid-cell text-left no-padding padding-right cell-auto-width">
            <div class="svg-icon no-width no-padding white" data-role="ico_RoundStar"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path> <path d="M11.99 2C6.47 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.47 10 9.99 10C17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12S17.52 2 11.99 2zm4.24 16L12 15.45 7.77 18l1.12-4.81-3.73-3.23 4.92-.42L12 5l1.92 4.53 4.92.42-3.73 3.23L16.23 18z"></path></svg></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-cell no-padding flex flex-vcenter">
            <p class="text-left white">Opportunities</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row padding-top">
        <div class="grid-cell no-padding padding-top padding-bottom text-left flex flex-vcenter">
            <span class="heading white no-line-height">0</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: inside your function call add e.preventDefault();

Comment: Thanks @hunzaboy, but I don't want to use JavaScript.

Comment: Any reason that you can't just remove the `href=''`?

Comment: @gavgrif that is not true. It is perfectly valid in HTML5. https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/links.html#element-attrdef-a-href

Comment: @Turnip - thank you for teaching me a thing - I completely thought it was invalid markup. I was wrong. Cheeers :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;` on `a` tag, it will work.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
.fc-card-header {
  background: #1976d2;
  padding: 24px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
}
.svg-icon svg {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}
```

```html
<a href="cmOpportunitySummary" class="white">
  <div class="fc-card-header">
    <div class="grid-row">
      <div class="grid-cell text-left no-padding padding-right cell-auto-width">
        <div class="svg-icon no-width no-padding white" data-role="ico_RoundStar">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
            <path d="M11.99 2C6.47 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.47 10 9.99 10C17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12S17.52 2 11.99 2zm4.24 16L12 15.45 7.77 18l1.12-4.81-3.73-3.23 4.92-.42L12 5l1.92 4.53 4.92.42-3.73 3.23L16.23 18z"></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-cell no-padding flex flex-vcenter">
        <p class="text-left white">Opportunities</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row padding-top">
      <div class="grid-cell no-padding padding-top padding-bottom text-left flex flex-vcenter">
        <span class="heading white no-line-height">0</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: @Sravan `pointer-events:none` works with all type of elements, but somehow in this case it's not working with `a`, because of wrapping block element into inline element I guess. or maybe because of inappropriate `URL` format `<a href="cmOpportunitySummary" class="white">`

Comment: It seems to work with all inline elements. That´s a CSS quirk?

Answer (score 0):

I had button tag in my case. Adding display: inline-block helped in case of safari browser on MAC.

```
<button
    className={props.btnClass} 
    style={{padding:props.btnPadding}}
    onClick={props.btnAction}
>
    {props.btnTitlle}
</button>
```

Below is the CSS:

```
button.disabledBtn {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background: #7eb2ec;
    border: 2px solid #7eb2ec;
    margin-right: 22px;
    font-weight: initial;
    &:active {
      display: inline-block;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  }
```