# Not able to make the whole div content readonly by default and enable editing when click on edit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have attached an image here below.

[image]

In the above picture. There are two buttons in the top right corner. My requirement is when I load this page everything in this page including save button should be disabled except edit button. When I click on edit, the page should be able to edit that is page should be enabled. Is it possible to do it as I am expecting.

Here below I have attached my code. I am using angularjs for numeric slider.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--Links for header file-->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- The below url are required for dropdown -->
    <link href="http://localhost/Test/css/fselect.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://localhost/Test/js/fSelect.js"></script>

    <!-- The below url are required for numeric slidebar -->
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.9/angular-material.css'>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.9/docs.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/Performance/navbar/css/styleForNavbar.css"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        #container{
            height:1000px;
            max-height:400px;
            overflow-y:scroll;
        }
        #well{
            background-color: white;
        }
        #testconfig{
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
        body{
            overflow-x: hidden;
            background-color: white;
        }

    </style>

    <script>
    (function($) {
        $(function() {  
            $('#filename').fSelect();
            $('#inst_type').fSelect();
            $('#browsers').fSelect();
            $('#region').fSelect();
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>

    <script>
        function ConfirmDelete() {
              return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete test?");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<?php
    $Files = array('trial.txt','info.txt','log.txt');
    $RFiles = array('trial.txt');
    $MSize = array('micro','macro');
    $size = 'micro';
?>
<body>
<div id="contentcontainer">
<form method="post" action="insertdata.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" name="runconfig">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div>
                    <a><h3>Default</h3></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><span><h4><?php
                    if(isset($_POST['duplicate'])){
                        echo '<input class="form-control" type="text" value="test" name="testname" pattern=".{6,50}" title="Enter min 6 letters and max 50 letters" required >';
                    }
                    else{
                        echo '<input class="form-control" type="text" value="test" name="testname" pattern=".{6,50}" title="Enter min 6 letters and max 50 letters" required >';
                    }?></h4></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="buttons"><br/>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="submit" name="edit" class="btn btn-primary"><b>Edit</b></button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-success"><b>Save</b></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><hr/>

    <div class="well" id="well">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="btn-group col-md-4">
            <div class="TestHistory">
                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-4"><b>History</b></button>
            </div>
            <div class="TestCofiguration">
                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-4" id="testconfig"><b>Configuration</b></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>

        <div name="toggle" id="hideandshow">
            <!--<fieldset disabled>-->

            <div class="row" id="runtest">
                <center><h3>Edit if you need</h3></center>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row" id="container">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-xs-6"><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                                <div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                                            <span><b>Filename</b></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <select  name="filename[]" id="filename" multiple="multiple">
                                            <optgroup label="Filename"> 
                                                <?php
                                                    for ($x = 0; $x < count($Files); $x++) {
                                                        $i=0;
                                                        for ($y = 0; $y < count($RFiles); $y++) {
                                                            if(strcmp($Files[$x],$RFiles[$x])==0){
                                                                echo "<option id='file' value='".$Files[$x]."' selected='selected'>".$Files[$x]."</option>";
                                                                $i=1;
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        if ($i!=1){
                                                            echo "<option id='file' value='".$Files[$x]."'>".$Files[$x]."</option>";
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                            </optgroup>
                                        </select>
                                <div style="display:none; text-align:center; color:red" class="error" id="filechoose_error" >&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;  * select a file</div>
                                </div><br/>

                                <div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                                        <span><b>Machine Size</b></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <select style="margin-left:1cm" name="inst_type" id="inst_type">
                                        <?php
                                            for ($x = 0; $x < count($MSize); $x++) {
                                                if($MSize[$x]==$size){
                                                    echo "<option value='".$MSize[$x]."' selected>".$MSize[$x]."</option>";
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                    echo "<option value='".$MSize[$x]."'>".$MSize[$x]."</option>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div><br/>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <br/><br/>
                                <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="sliderdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp" style= background-color: white">
                                    <md-content style="margin: 16px; padding:10px; background-color: white">
                                        <md-slider-container>
                                          <span class="md-body-1 col-xs-4"><b>Numbers</b></span>
                                          <md-slider ng-model="disabled" min="1" max="100" aria-label="Disabled" md-discrete="" id="blue-slider" class="md-primary" style="margin-left: 60px;">
                                          </md-slider>
                                          </md-slider>
                                          <md-input-container>
                                            <input type="number" id="Concurrency" name="Concurrency" ng-model="disabled" min="1" max="100" ng-init="disabled=10" aria-label="blue" aria-controls="blue-slider">
                                          </md-input-container>
                                        </md-slider-container>
                                    </md-content>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-8" style="margin-left:10px">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <label for="chkCache">Cash</label>
                                        <input type="radio" name ="radio" class="cache" value="true" id="radio" checked/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <label for="chkCache" id="without cache">No cash</label>
                                        <input type="radio" name  ="radio" class="cache" value="false" id="radio">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><br/>
                </div>
                <!--</fieldset>-->
            </div>
        </div><hr/>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

    <!-- The below links are related to the slidebar-->
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-animate.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-route.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-aria.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.9/angular-material.js'></script>

    <script>
    angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
      .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.color = {
          red: Math.floor(Math.random() * 255),
          green: Math.floor(Math.random() * 255),
          blue: Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
        };

      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can achieve this simply by adding a transparent layer on bottom section so no one can click o any element. And disable layer on click of edit.

Comment: You can add overlay OR you can add a class to all the elements and disable on load and later on enable it on the click of edit button.

Comment: May I ask what the use of that requirement is? Just have an "Edit" page where users can edit and save the fields?

Comment: Lets say you have selected some values and it is stored somewhere. You want to see the selected values now. Then we display this page as a default value as your inputs. And If you want to edit, you need to click on edit then only you should be able to edit and save. @kerbholz

Comment: Ok, I see. Personally I'd use a "view/show" page where you can view the data for a specific item and a different "edit" page where you can edit/save that data. But that's just me. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

Simply put you complete form in fieldset tag and add disabled attribute to this fieldset tag.

```
<fieldset disabled>
    FIELDS_TO_BE_DISABLED
</fieldset>
```

Add disabled attribute to your save button as well

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="submit" id="edit-btn" name="edit" class="btn btn-primary"><b>Edit</b></button>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="submit" id="submit-btn" name="save" class="btn btn-success" disabled><b>Save</b></button>
</div>
```

On the click event of Edit Button just remove the disabled attribute from fieldset tag

```
$(function () {
    $('#edit-btn').click(function () {
       $('fieldset,#submit-btn').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Comment: It is working for only radio buttons. It is not disabling the drop down and numeric slider

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#well').css('pointer-events','none');
    });

    function edit_page() {
        $('#well').css('pointer-events','');
    }
```

Comment: People are saying using pointer may lead to the issues. Because in some OS like linux may have other symbols rather than pointer. So Is there any way to overcome from this? @Vikrant

Comment: It is not because of OS, HTML is independent of any OS type. But if issue occurs, it can be resolved adding `display:block` OR `display:pointer-block`.. [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42224919/3682162)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Css Property Display like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="show">Show</button>
<button type="button" id="hide">hide</button>
<div id="div" style="Display:none;">
  div content
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("#div").css("display", "block");
    });
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#div").css("display", "none");
    });
});
</script>
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/deepakvaishnav/ocspbtzj/15/

Answer (score 0):

As you didnot mention if you want edit window to be visible.

```
  <div   [hidden]="!visible"
      class="toggle">
    //show stuff
  </div>
```